Error react native: me diero un repositorio de RN, pero no tiene las carpetas android ni ios
me pasaron un repositorio de React native, pero cuando lo clone, veo que no tiene las carpetas de Android ni de IOs, por ende no puedo ejecutarlo. como puedo generar esas carpetas?
Por otro lado, intente crear un nuevo proyecto de react native y copiar todos los archivos, pero cuando creo un nuevo proyecto, me lo crea con React 16 y React Native 0.74, y mi proyecto anterior usa React 18 y React Native 0.72, como puedo crear un proyecto nuevo con estas versiones especificas

el archivo package te dice mucho, dale una leida, como comento @Ricardo Alba puede que sea con expo.

quizá sea un proyecto React Native con Expo.
[https://docs.expo.dev/tutorial/create-your-first-app/]
quizá te pueda ayudar la documentación.
Se puede levantar tanto con expo o npm.
No te compliques,
Saludos!

Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas en el centro de ayuda.
